cleaning up full directories at once
right now, i have a filesystem that fills up fairly regularly. the TL;DR is that I can't introduce better log rotation, and the files must be deleted regularly.
let's say i have the following output from df -h;
/dev/mapper/atom0-common                2.0G   28K  1.8G   1% /data/services/common
/dev/mapper/atom0-atx_ctx               49G  9.4G   38G  21% /data/services/atx_ctx
/dev/mapper/atom0-cores                 2.9G   24K  2.8G   100% /data/services/cores
/dev/mapper/atom0-clusterd_logs         172M   24K  158M   1% /logs/clusterd
/dev/mapper/atom0-kms_logs              172M   14M  145M   9% /logs/kms
/dev/mapper/atom0-speaker_logs          172M   48M  110M  31% /logs/speaker
/dev/mapper/atom0-appsshd_logs          90M   24K   83M   1% /logs/appsshd
/dev/mapper/atom0-keyhole_logs          172M  1.2M  157M   1% /logs/keyhole
/dev/mapper/atom0-loghandler_logs       90M  2.8M   80M   4% /logs/loghandler
/dev/mapper/atom0-k8_logs               2.0G  202M  1.6G  100% /logs/k8

What I'd like to do is have a single script that searches for ALL >80% full filesystems, and then deletes ALL .log and .gz files in said directories.
So far I've been able to narrow it down to
df -h | awk '{ print $5, $6}'  | sed 's/%//'

which returns just the file usage as a number, and the directory
1 /data/services/common
21 /data/services/atx_ctx
100 /data/services/cores
1 /logs/clusterd
9 /logs/kms
31 /logs/speaker
1 /logs/appsshd
1 /logs/keyhole
4 /logs/loghandler
100 /logs/k8

but this is where I'm getting stuck. I'm not sure how to take this output, look only at the first number, determine if it's greater than 80, and if so - execute find . -type f -name '.log' -delete and find . -type f -name '.gz' -delete on the directory to clear up the logs.

"What i'd like to do is have a single script that searches for ALL >80% full filesystems, and then deletes ALL .log and .gz files in said directories." That is far too dangerous. Let's find a better way.

Depending on your application, deleting the log files might not free up the space. The space will not be reclaimed if the application has the file open. Is there a reason why you cannot use logrotate?

why are you using these miniature volumes? That sounds like the source of the problem!

Are you perhaps trying to reinvent filesystem quotas?

I'm agree with Marcus: using df as is is a really bad idea.
The df output with any options is not usable in complete safety by a script (like many other commands).
Image the result of your command if your device name and/or your mount path contains spaces :(
But it's possible to choose your ouput columns and order (like with ps command) like this:
df --output=pcent,target

@see man df for all available columns
After that you could make filters:

No first line
Remove percent char
Remove disque under 80%
Remove first space
Do not execute on root directory!

And finally: print mounted points with nul char delimited
df -a --output=pcent,target \
| awk 'NR==1 {next} {sub("%","")} $1 < 80 {next} {$1=""; sub(/^ /, "")} {printf("%s%c", $0, 0)}'

Note: add a | cat -v to see nul char as ^@ and remove it.
So, execute what you want on each result item with xargs command:
df -a --output=pcent,target \
| awk 'NR==1 {next} {sub("%","")} $1 < 10 {next} {$1=""; sub(/^ /, "")} {printf("%s%s", $0, 0)}' \
| xargs -0 -I % \
  find "%" -name "*.log" -exec \
       ls -l "{}" \;

